# How assign data to redux initial state array

Tags: reactjs, redux

If I have the initial state in my reducer like that:

```
let initialState = {
  id: 1,
  url: 'http://',
  name: 'jjj',
  List: []
};
```

and I want to assign values into this object from different action.types 
e.g:

```
List: [
  {
    name: 'a1',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'a2',
    id: 2
  }
]
```

here is my reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NAME_A:
      return { ...state, List: action.payload };
    case SET_NAME_B:
      return { ...state, List: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

my `action.payload` giving to me value of input for name a and name b they are different inputs how I can do that?

Comment: You want to replace the value inserted in the list or add a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean adding element to array in reducer?

```
return { 
        ...state,
        List: [...state.List, action.payload]
    }
```

Comment: Yes i mean that

Comment: is it fix your problem?

Comment: no i'm getting eror like: TypeError: state.List is not iterable.. o sorry it'm my mistake of syntax.. worked well thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spread reducer so that you just need to update the List :

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NAME_A:
      return { ...state, List: [...state.List,action.payload ]}; //You can add more conditions base on action
    case SET_NAME_B:
      return { ...state, List: [...state.List,action.payload ] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```